# ANTLR4 How can I set sourceName?

Tags: antlr

I created a parser using ANTLR4 and it works nicely with files.
Now when I try to parse from URLs directly the Token's getSourceName() method returns "unknown". This is an issue in error messages that I'd like to be as clear as possible.

So I'd like to have the URL that I retrieved the input from as the source name, but I do not see where I can set that value. This is what my code looks like:

```
private parseDocument(URL u) {
    URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
    CharStream charStream = CharStreams.fromStream(conn.getInputStream());
    MyLexer lexer = new MyLexer(charStream);
    CommonTokenStream tokenstream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    MyParser parser = new MyParser(tokenstream);
    MyParser.ParseContext pc = parser.parse();
    ...
}
```

Is there something like setSourceName(String) method, be it on the CharStream or the lexer? Or what is the intended way to provide this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [source code of CharStreams](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/CharStreams.java):

```java
public static CharStream fromStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    return fromStream(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}

public static CharStream fromStream(InputStream is, Charset charset) throws IOException {
    return fromStream(is, charset, -1);
}

public static CharStream fromStream(InputStream is, Charset charset, long inputSize) throws IOException {
    try (ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(is)) {
        return fromChannel(
            channel,
            charset,
            DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE,
            CodingErrorAction.REPLACE,
            IntStream.UNKNOWN_SOURCE_NAME,
            inputSize);
    }
}

...

public static CodePointCharStream fromChannel(
    ReadableByteChannel channel,
    Charset charset,
    int bufferSize,
    CodingErrorAction decodingErrorAction,
    String sourceName,
    long inputSize) throws IOException
{
    ...
}
```

you see that all `fromStream(...)` calls end up as a `fromChannel(...)` call, which is `public` so can be used like this (untested though):

```java
URL u = ...
URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(conn.getInputStream());

CharStream charStream = CharStreams.fromChannel(
        channel,
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
        4096,
        CodingErrorAction.REPLACE,
        u.getPath(),
        -1);
```